# Google cardboard cursor firing off multiple times

Tags: reactjs, google-cardboard, aframe

I'm currently playing around with a VR environment for Google cardboard, using React and A-Frame and have a bug that I cannot fix.

I'm using a fuse-type cursor that will fire off a click event upon gazing at a target for more than 1.5 seconds. It's supposed to fire off once, but for some reason it will fire off multiple times.

You can check out the app on the browser at https://vr-museum.herokuapp.com

The code for the cursor:

```
    <Camera  position={this.state.cameraPos} >
      <Cursor fuse="true" max-distance="10" timeout="1500" color="red"/>
    </Camera>
```

Any insight as to what may be going on will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: just to be curious: Why don't you use [React VR](https://facebookincubator.github.io/react-vr/index.html). **React VR lets you build VR apps using only JavaScript. It uses the same design as React, letting you compose a rich VR world and UI from declarative components.**

Comment: React VR wasn't available at the time. It definitely looks promising and I will be watching as it develops. Thank you for the input :)

Comment: Why do you suggest React VR? A-Frame lets you do it with HTML and JavaScript with no build steps. And you can use React if you want, except aframe-react has way less overhead because it lets A-Frame handle the 3D work and only let React handle views and state. React VR is less mature as well.

Answer (score 0):

This has changed to `fuse-timeout="1500"`. I will update docs shortly.